# Windows Printer Enumeration. Why is there a difference between native C++ and C# implementations

Tags: c#, c++, windows, printing, network-printers

I'm woking on a C# program that needs to enumerate windows print queues on a network. So basically I use P/Invoke to call the **EnumPrinters** defined in the Winspool.drv dll.
It works fine when I query for local printers (defined on the workstation I'm running), but when it comes to remote print servers / printers I have a problem.

Let me show the details of my C# code:
First the P/Invoke definition of EnumPrinters:

```
     [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
     public static extern bool EnumPrintersW(uint Flags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Name, uint Level, System.IntPtr pPrinterEnum, uint cbBuf, ref uint pcbNeeded, ref uint pcReturned);
```

When I call EnumPrintersW I first call with empty parameters in order to get the amount of memory needed. I'll use **Marshal.AllocHGlobal** to allocate the response buffer, and then call EnumPrintersW again with the updated parameters
The first sequence of calls to find remote print servers is:

```
     bool cc = EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE, String.Empty, 1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);
     IntPtr pPrts = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbNeeded);
     bool cc = EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE, String.Empty, 1, pPrts, cbNeeded, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);
```

This sequence will return a number of PRINTER_INFO_1W structs. One of them is (example):

```
 "LanMan Print Services!!\\COMPIX"
```

The next sequence of calls to EnumPrintersW is intended to find the shared printers defined on server "COMPIX", but the first call to EnumPrintersW will return false. I have tried to call **GetLastError** which returns 5 (Access is Denied):

```
     bool cc = EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_NAME, "LanMan Print Services!!\\COMPIX", 1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);
     // returns false
     // The next lines of code is not called in my real program
     IntPtr pPrts = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbNeeded);
     bool cc = EnumPrintersW(PRINTER_ENUM_NAME, "LanMan Print Services!!\\COMPIX", 1, pPrts, cbNeeded, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);
```

**The tricky part is**, I have the exactly same code written in C++, and here the same sequence of calls returns the list of printers on server COMPIX (as I expected).

So my question is simple: What am I doing wrong in the C# code ? Since the GetLastError returned access is denied, could it be some permissions I need to initialize in the managed space?

Thanks in advance